# MySQL Delete Records Older Than X Minutes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've searched quite a bit and found a few solutions that did not end up working for me and can't understand why.

I have a table with a timestamp column.  The MySQL type for this column is 'datetime'.  I insert into this table the following from PHP.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

This enters, what looks like the correct value for the MySQL date time.

```
2012-06-28 15:31:46
```

I want to use this column to delete rows that are older than, say, 10 minutes.  I'm running the following query, but it's not working.  It affects 0 rows.

```
DELETE FROM adminLoginLog WHERE timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);
```

Can anyone shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong and why it's not working properly?

Thanks.

Comment: try my Update 1 answer and let me know what you get...

Comment: @FahimParkar thanks.  I've just tried that but it did not work.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since TIMESTAMP() is a built-in function that returns the current time stamp, your query will never return any results.

Try wrapping the column in back ticks to let MySQL know you mean the column, not the reserved word:

```
DELETE FROM adminLoginLog WHERE `timestamp` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);
```

Comment: Interesting.  I did not think of that at all, thanks.  However the query still affects 0 rows and there are plenty that should be deleted.  Given this however, I'm going to go back and try some of the other queries I found online and make sure I wrap the column name in backticks.

Comment: @sajanNOPPIX, I tested your query with the backticks and it seems to work for me. What issue are you having? You might want to check your data. Time zone issue?

Comment: I think the issue may be that I'm using the DATETIME datatype when I should be using TIMESTAMP in MySQL.  I'm updating my database and adding a few new records with this and will try it out in just a bit.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @sajanNOPPIX, `NOW()` works fine with either TIMESTAMP or DATETIME columns. MySQL does the conversion. The problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

`timestamp` is a reserved keyword in mysql. To use `timestamp` as a field name, you have to put that in backticks as shown below.

```
`timestamp`
```

If time_created is a **unix timestamp (int)**, you should be able to use something like this:

```
DELETE FROM adminLoginLog WHERE `timestamp` < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 600);
```

(600 seconds = 10 minutes - obviously)

Otherwise (if time_created is **mysql timestamp**), you could try this:

```
DELETE FROM adminLoginLog WHERE `timestamp` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

### Update 1

```
DELETE FROM adminLoginLog WHERE `timestamp` < DATE_SUB( CURRENT_TIME(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

### Update 2

```
DELETE FROM adminLoginLog WHERE `timestamp` < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c426e/1)

Comment: Thanks.  Your original answer actually helped me figure it out.  My column was using the DATETIME datatype, which doesn't seem to support functions like NOW().  I switch it to the TIMESTAMP datatype and everything began to work.

Comment: @sajanNOPPIX : That's great. Also rename field name `timestamp` to something else... e.g. myDate or timeEntered...

Comment: @sajanNOPPIX : With datetime, NOW works, however there is need of `DATE_SUB `

Answer (score 0):

I'd produce the timestamp in php, then pass it into your mysql query:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify("-10 minutes")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct, if you have access to phpmyadmin execute the command in the SQL console that will give you some more information.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Code :

```
//Your Database Details

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tifu");

//Actual Core thing

$delete_otp = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM temp_project_member_details WHERE create_at < ('" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). "' - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)");
```

Note : 
Here temp_project_member_details : Table Name in the database tifu

and create_at : Field name inside the Table temp_project_member_details which has Date and Time stored using the same function `'" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). "'`

[Screenshot of Deleting After 10 minute code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pS4B.jpg)

[Screenshot of the storage of Date and Time in the create_at field of table as described in answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ETZj.jpg)