# Selecting records older than 15 days ago

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i display only records older then 15 days ago by the column `updatetime` ?

Code

```
    $conn = mysql_connect($servername,$database_username,$database_password);
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user_shift_test2';
    $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $result )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $i=1;
```

While loop which is fetching all the rows

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
      echo '<tr>';
        $res = $row['userid'];
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='$res'></td>";

       echo 
        "<td>{$row['userid']}  <br> </td>".
       "<td>{$row['id']}  <br> </td>".
              "<td>{$row['name']}  <br> </td>".
              "<td>{$row['shifttime']}  <br> </td>".
              "<td>{$row['dayoff']}  <br> </td>".
              "<td>{$row['updatetime']}  <br> </td></tr>";
              } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Delete Records Older Than X Minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252704/mysql-delete-records-older-than-x-minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in pure SQL , filter the records on the DB side. Try using [`DATE_SUB()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp) :

```
SELECT * FROM user_shift_test2 t
WHERE t.updatetime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

Comment: to check i can also use `INTERVAL 2 MINUTES` ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to use the word `MINUTE` and not `MINUTES`

Comment: THANK YOU bro it helped me alot.